# OnDemand Feature Download SDK greater than 20MB in Android?

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, google-play-core

I am working on a project where I need an SDK which is of 20MB size only in a certain case. I mean the usage is still low, but due to that my app size is getting bigger as I include that aar file.

Is there a way to use it or download the SDK only when I need it?

I went through [Dynamic feature module delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/dynamic-delivery) but couldn't find a way to use the SDK. Is it even possible to do it?

Please help with some solution in how to achieve this.

Comment: This is an AAR that you built and published? You say you "couldn't find a way to use" it. Did you successfully download the feature?

Comment: @spartygw I meant that, is it possible to do that? I mean can I download the SDK on demand and use it. Any SDK. If yes, then how to implement it?